# How to send POST data to a reversed url

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, http-post

I have `HttpResponseRedirect()` function which constructs the required url:

my `create` view:

```
def create(request):
    entry = Char_field(field=request.POST['record'])
    entry.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('db:index_page',kwargs={'redirected':'true'}))
```

the view which the `HttpResponseRedirect()` redirects to is:

```
def index(request):
    redirected = False
    template= 'app/index.html'
    try:
        if request.POST['redirected'] is 'true':
            redirected = True
    except:
        pass
    return render(request,template,{'redirected':redirected})
```

However it returns an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /app/create/
Reverse for 'index_page' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'redirected': 'true'}' not found.
```

## urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index_page'),
    url(r'^get_record/$',views.get_record,name='get_record'),
    url(r'^create/$',views.create_html,name='create_path'),
    url(r'^add/$',views.create,name='add_record')
)
```

Why is this so and Is it possible send `POST` data to the `index_page` view through the `reverse()` function?

Comment: Show us your `urls.py` with the definition of `db:index_page`.

Comment: Pretty clear: `index_name` doesn't take any parameters in the URL definition, so `reverse` can't find the location and throws an error.

Comment: @Matthias that's the point, I'm trying to send the data as a `POST` request through the `reverse` function

Comment: @KDawG Well, you can't do that, because then you'd need to change the headers.

Comment: HTTP redirects can't contain POST data. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024168/django-how-do-i-redirect-a-post-and-pass-on-the-post-data for details and possible solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question isn't actually anything to do with POST data. You are simply trying to reverse with a parameter, but the URL for `index_page` doesn't take one. That would be true whether or not you were wanting to POST to that URL.

Then, of course, you *don't* actually POST to that URL, you simply return HttpResponseRedirect, which does a 302 redirect.

I'm not sure why you think you need this parameter in the POST. If you don't want to put it in the URL pattern, why not just in the GET params?

```
url = reverse('db:index_page') + '?redirected=true'
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

and in the receiving view:

```
redirect = request.GET.get('redirected')
```