# Django: How to return user to correct pagination page after CreateView form_invalid?

Tags: django, django-views, django-pagination

I have a paginated comments page. Pagination is provided by django-endless-pagination. When clicking to new paginated pages a get parameter is append to the url. Such as `?page=4`.

Each comment on each paginated page displays a 'reply to' comment form containing a captcha field.

My view uses CreateView and I implement form_invalid myself in order to add some data to the context variable. At the end of my form_invalid method I return `self.render_to_response(context)`

**The Problem**

If a user attempts to reply to a comment when on page 4, and that user supplies and invalid captcha, then the pagination get parameter (`?page=4`) is lost during the response.

How can I redirect to the full path (keeping get params) and pass context data along with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024168/django-how-do-i-redirect-a-post-and-pass-on-the-post-data), but my scenario is a little different given that I want to maintain my form state (the captcha error mentioned in question) in the redirect.

Thank you @petkostas for pointing out `HTTP_REFERER`

My resolution to this involved storing the context in cache with a cache key derived from the current timestamp. I redirect to the (same) comments url, but in doing this I append the current comment page as a get parameter and also the timestamp as another get parameter.

Then during get requests the view checks for the existence of the timestamp parameter. If it is provided, then a cache.get call is made to retrieve the needed context data. And finally, the cached item is deleted.

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils.dateformat import format

class MyView(CreateView):
    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'form': form,
            ... other context stuff ...
        }

        timestamp = format(datetime.now(), u'U')
        cache.set('invalid_context_{0}'.format(timestamp), context)

        page = 1
        full_path = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        if '?' in full_path:
            query_string = full_path.split('?')[1].split('&')
            for q in query_string:
                if q.startswith('page='):
                    page = q.split('=')[1]

        response = redirect('my_comments_page')
        response['Location'] += '?page={0}&x={1}'.format(page, timestamp)
        return response

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
           ... add context stuff ...
        })

        if 'x' in self.request.GET:
            x = self.request.GET.get('x')
            cache_key = 'invalid_context_{0}'.format(x)
            invalid_context = cache.get(cache_key)
            if invalid_context:
                context.update(invalid_context)
                cache.delete(cache_key)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used django-endless-pagination, but Django offers 2 ways to get either the full current request path, or the Refferer of the request:
In your view or template (check documentation on how to use request in templates) for the referring requesting page:

```
request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

Or for the current request full path:

```
request.full_path()
```

Comment: Thank you @petkostas for responding. My problem is that I don't know how to redirect to the full path and send the context data along with it. I will edit my question.