# Django: resetting password without a CSRF token

Tags: android, django, django-users, django-csrf, forgot-password

I have a Django website that manages [`Users`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#user-objects). Using the built-in functionality, users can request a password reset from the website and that works great. I have implemented it [according to this tutorial](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html) so I am using [the built-in password reset functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset).

I have an Android app from which users should also be able to request a password reset. The problem is that I do not have a [CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/) in the application, and the [the built-in `password_reset` method has the `@csrf_protect` decorator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L145). This means that I cannot access it without a CSRF token and I also can't modify it with the [@csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator.

So the next idea is to create a function, which generates a CSRF token, stores it in the request and redirects to the correct URL which sends the reset email. The problem is that [according to this, django does not allow to pass POST parameters further in a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024528).

Therefore my question is **how can I request a password reset in Django without a CSRF token**? Alternatively, **what is the correct way to request this from an application**?

Comment: Do you know the user? Then just make the request to the site within the function (see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), instead of doing a redirect and return the response to the request. That way you can put what ever you want in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Please feel free to post any alternative solutions. One that doesn't require two separate requests would be particularly great.

If you look at [the password_reset method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L145), you can see that it only tries to process the request as a reset request if the request method is POST. Otherwise it just returns a `TemplateResponse` containing a form. This also contains the CSRF token as a cookie.

So first, I send a GET request to `http://myaddress.com/user/password/reset/` and extract the CSRF cookie from the response. Then I send a POST request containing the cookie, the email address and 2 headers (see below).

This is the code I've implemented to achieve this from `Android` (trimmed):

```
String url = "http://myaddress.com/user/password/reset/";
```

**GET Request:**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);

Cookie csrfCookie = null;
for (Cookie cookie : cookieStore.getCookies()) {
    if (cookie.getName() == "csrftoken") {
        csrfCookie = cookie;
        break;
    }
}

if (csrfCookie == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException("CSRF cookie not found!");
}

return csrfCookie;
```

Note that you want the `CookieStore` from `org.apache.http.client`.

**POST Request:**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

// Prepare the cookie store to receive cookies.
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
cookieStore.addCookie(csrfCookie);
httpPost.setHeader("Referer", url);
httpPost.setHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrfCookie.getValue());
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addTextBody("email", emailAddressToReset);
httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
    throw new Exception("Could not reset password!");
}

Toast.makeText(context, "Password reset requested! Please check your email inbox!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```