# To redirect to URL which accepts POST requests only in Django

Tags: python, django, redirect, http-post

I am currently working on a project based on Django framework which requires APIs to be built that accept POST requests only except one or two which can receive GET requests.

One of those apis, say /x/, is invoked on the submission of form with method type as POST. The view attached to this api /x/ modifies the request and then needs to invoke another API(say /y/) or view which again accepts POST requests only.

My code is as follows :

**views.py**

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
import logging

#print "__name__ : " + __name__
logger = logging.getLogger('django.request')
logger_info = logging.getLogger('correct_info')

#to_be_commented
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def load_filter(request):

        context = RequestContext(request)
        if request.method == 'POST':

                print request.data
                filter_list = request.POST.getlist('profile')
                print filter_list

                stdd_filters = ['gender','state','country','examEnrolled','examDefault','examSelected']
                profFilters = {}
                #profFilters['filters'] = {}
                for flter in stdd_filters:
                        if flter in filter_list:
                                profFilters[flter] = request.POST.getlist(flter)
                        else:
                                profFilters[flter] = []
                print profFilters 
                if not request.POST._mutable:
                    request.POST._mutable = True



                request.POST['filters'] = profFilters

                if 'AND' in request.data:
                     print "TRUE AND"
                     **#problem here**
                     #return redirect('profile_filter_and')
                     return HttpResponseRedirect('../filtered/and/')

        elif request.method == 'GET':
             return render(request,"filters.html",{})

@api_view(['POST'])    
def profile_filter_and(request):
      if request.method == POST:
         #entire code
```

I have tried both redirect and HttpResponseRedirect methods but both of them call the url or view functions as a GET request due to which I get the following error :

```
HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

whereas I want the redirection as POST request to the url or view since it accepts only POST requests. I have tried searching about the same on Internet but haven't got anything fruitful. I am a beginner in developing APIs in Django.

Answer (score 2):

"I have tried both redirect and HttpResponseRedirect methods but both of them call the url or view functions as a GET"

This is because redirecting POST data is considered bad design choice and is not supported by Django in any obvious way. Check out this answer to similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024528/4400065

One simple solution to your problem would be passing data to function, instead of sending antoher HTTP request.