# Passing parameters to view from submitted form

Tags: django

I'm trying to pass some parameters received from a submitted form (POST) to a ListView so that I can generate the relevant queryset based on those parameters.

I'm not clear if the parameters should be specified in the URL in addition to the View?

From current View:

```
        area = form.cleaned_data['area']
        service = form.cleaned_data['service']
        usage = form.cleaned_data['usage']

        return redirect('users:results', area=area, service=service, usage=usage)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), {}, name="results", ),
```

views.py

```
class ResultsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'site/results.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    context_object_name = 'results'

    def get_queryset(self, area, service, usage):
        results = Results.objects.filter(area=area, service=service, usage=usage)
        return results
```

Comment: may be this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024168/django-how-do-i-redirect-a-post-and-pass-on-the-post-data

Comment: Hmmm from the HTTP restriction, it looks like it's not possible to use a redirect with POST data. Is there a better method instead? - call the view function directly and pass the parameters in (as this looks like a fairly common problem - ie accept data from form to generate a specific list of results to display based on the form data)

Comment: Why does it need to be a post, and why do you need to redirect? Why not use a GET and just show the response directly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by show the response directly? Do you mean in the same view?

Comment: I'm using a POST request here as some of the user data is slightly sensitive(this is a shortened example) and I would rather not expose it in the URL.

Comment: My be you can try storing the data in `request.session` and then read that in you `Listview's` `get` method.

Comment: Thanks I have stored it in a session for now, but that requires it to be stateful and it feels like there should be a better solution than saving the data to the session only to be used in the next view.