# Redirecting after Ajax 'POST'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a code of adding products list. when the user clicked the button a function is called which send the products list to the views by using ajax

```
function submition(container){
     $.ajax({
        url :'/compare_in/',
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            com_list : container,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        success : function() {
            console.log('success')
        },
        error : function() {
            console.log('Failure');
        }
    });

}
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [path('compare_in/', views.compare_in)]
```

now in the views code, the product's list value is manipulating and scraping the data by the list value and storing the data in the dictionary

```
def compare_in(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    compare_res = request.POST.getlist('com_list[]')
    for item in range(len(compare_res)):
        if re.compile('edmi').search(compare_res[item]):
            compare_res[item] = 'xiaomi ' + compare_res[item]
    phone_list = ','.join(e.lower() for e in compare_res)
    phone_list = '-'.join(phone_list.split())
    .
    .
    .
    return HTTPResponse()
```

now I want to redirect to the different page with the value of the dictionary.

Note-return render() is not working

Comment: The `django` view will not be able to redirect to a new page. You should return a new url as part of your response, and do a `window.location('redirect_url')` inside the `sucess` function...

Comment: nothing happing..i updated success fun to success : function() {
                window.location.url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/compare_in';
            }

Comment: You need to do `window.location.assign("127.0.0.1:8000/compare_in")`

Comment: but how to pass the dictionary to the template

Comment: Well, if you need to pass some `context` data, then I believe you will need to use a regular `django` form. Otherwise you can build an `url` and pass the data you need as a `querystring` like: `window.location.assign("127.0.0.1:8000/compare_in?param1=x&param2=y")`

Comment: I want to build a URL but don't know how to do using ajax. can you explain to me.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer from another thread: [Django: How do I redirect a post and pass on the post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024168/django-how-do-i-redirect-a-post-and-pass-on-the-post-data)

Also, it might be a good idea that you pass the data via URL param when redirecting.

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def compare_in(request):
    # rest of your code

    return redirect('https://example.com/{0}'.format(some['data']))
```

Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Sample codes: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/05/05/django-tip-1-redirect.html

Comment: thank you for the response. it's not redirecting me to the another page