# How to pass data in django redirect?

Tags: django

I want to pass JSON data with redirect URL, I used HttpResponseRedirect

```
path('session_data_req/', SessionDataFetch.as_view(url='http://0.0.0.0:8080/reciever/')),


class SessionDataFetch(APIView):

    url = None
    pattern_name = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        url = self.get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
        data = {"a": "a", "b": "b"}

        return HttpResponseRedirect(url, data=data)
```

but I am getting an error

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

I also tried to use

```
return redirect(url, kwargs={"ok", "ok"})
```

but not getting kwargs data in redirected URL views

```
class ReceiverView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        # data = request.data
        data = kwargs
        return Response({"a": "----| In receiver |----", "data": data})
```

response:

```
{
    "a": "----| In receiver |----",
    "data": {}
}
```

Is there any way to pass data in the redirect function?

Comment: just pass them as query params using ?data=jsonstring and in ReceiverView retrive them,The kwargs fetches only when there are path params

Comment: I have sensitive data ..so I am not passing in a params....        url = url + f"?data={data}"
..its working by query_params, I can encode and pass.. but ..I want to post and also want to know how can we pass post body data..

Comment: use sessions if require to store and clear the variable once retrieve. Or else put optional path param and pass kwargs

Comment: I want to post JSON body..not interested to store data.... here basically I need an answer how can we pass JSON data as we pass in post request APIs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024528/13499618
This is a restriction of HTTP that POST data cannot go with redirects.