# Passing values from the forms from one view (one url) to another view (second url) in Django

Tags: django

So I have two forms, and a view which enables users to fill them:

```
def input_view(request):    
    if request.method =="POST":
        simulation_form = SimulationSettings(request.POST)
        strategy_form = StrategySettings(request.POST)
        if simulation_form.is_valid() and strategy_form.is_valid():
            simulation_settings = simulation_form.cleaned_data
            strategy_settings = strategy_form.cleaned_data
            return render(
                request,
                "strategy_simulator/results_view.html",
                {"simulation_settings": simulation_settings, "strategy_settings": strategy_settings},
            )
    else:
        simulation_form = SimulationSettings()
        strategy_form = StrategySettings()
    return render(
        request,
        "strategy_simulator/input_view.html",
        {"simulation_form": simulation_form, "strategy_form": strategy_form},
    )
```

With this code, it works and after submitting the forms results_view.html template is displayed properly, but the url does not change and I want results to be under different url. So I've created second view and url to it, but I do not know how to pass forms values from one view to another and then redirect to the url connected to the specific view (results_view in this case). Here is the view:

```
def results_view(request):
    simulation_settings = request.POST.get('simulation_settings')
    strategy_settings = request.POST.get('strategy_settings')
    return render(
        request,
        "strategy_simulator/results_view.html",
        {"simulation_settings": simulation_settings, "strategy_settings": strategy_settings},
    )
```

And here are urls:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
        
app_name = "strategy_simulator"
urlpatterns = [
           path("results/", views.results_view, name="results_view"),
           path("", views.input_view, name="input_view"),
        ]
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Honestly  doesn't make much sense. Why not just send your form to `results_view` instead?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't best practice and not considered part of the [HTTP spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024528/3853907).

So, I don't suggest you do it. However, if you wanted to, note that views are just functions that accept a `request` as the first arg. If I'm not mistaken, this would work-

```
def results_view(request):
    ...
    return render(
        request,
        "strategy_simulator/results_view.html",
        {"simulation_settings": simulation_settings, "strategy_settings": strategy_settings},
    )

def input_view(request):    
    if request.method =="POST":
        simulation_form = SimulationSettings(request.POST)
        strategy_form = StrategySettings(request.POST)
        if simulation_form.is_valid() and strategy_form.is_valid():
            simulation_settings = simulation_form.cleaned_data
            strategy_settings = strategy_form.cleaned_data
            return results_view(request)

...
```

Rather, I'd suggest that your results_view uses query parameters (GET) instead of POST parameters, and you redirect to that if the forms are valid.